# Extract data from fields which contains multiple values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python programming and data mining. I am trying to read data from .csv file and store them as the list of dictionaries for analysis. But my data has multiple alternatives for a single column of values.
Here is my Data sample

[The screenshot of my data along with Highlighter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v37zk.jpg)

Since my column Fuels has Gas/Electricity I have City MPG as 16/81. However when I read this into my list of dictionaries, it isn't much of a problem, but if I want to compute an average or sum it gives an error.

I want to have such columns separated when I read the data into Python.

```
import csv

with open('mpg.csv') as f:
 a = [{k: (v) for k, v in row.items()}
  for row in csv.DictReader(f, skipinitialspace=True)]
print(a, '\n')
print(len(a))  # simply printing the data
print(a[0].keys()) # printing the Headers of the data
z = sum(float(d['City MPG']) for d in a) / len(a) # Error code
print(z)
```

The error is `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '33/81`.
I understand the error.

I am thinking of inserting such values in a Map, but not sure about the code.

Comment: can you share the sample file as an input here instead of screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the MPG fields on the `'/'`, float them, and then select the first one with `[0]`, or the second with `[1]`:

```
z = sum(float(d['City MPG'].split('/')[0]) for d in a) / len(a)
```

If you want the averages of both the first and the second values (for gas and electricity respecively), it could be done like this:

```
z = [d['City MPG'].split('/') for d in a]
city_mpg_gas, city_mpg_elec = [sum(float(values[i]) for values in z) / len(a)
                                    for i in range(len(a))]
print('city_mpg_gas:', city_mpg_gas)
print('city_mpg_elec:', city_mpg_elec)
```

Although I've never heard of a gallon of electricity... `;-)`

Comment: Since the split is set to [0], will this calculate the average for gas only or add the electricity as well to the average.

Comment: V.Bravo: If you use `[0]` it computes the average for gas only, with `[1]` it would compute the average for electricity only—doesn't mix them.

Comment: When I run with [1], it fails, stating that"Index out of Bounds". I think it is because all the data doesn't have electricity/ gas options. Some car models like Tesla just have electricity so using [0] is not the right approach.

Comment: It looks like you could check `d['Fuel']` to see whether there will be one or two values in the `d['City MPG']` column—or you could check to see whether `d['City MPG'].split('/')` returns a list of one or two values. If there is more than one value, then both `[0]` and `[1]` will work. For one value, only `[0]` would be a valid index.